# Replace part of string in mysql table column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation and I've broken the mysql database. For posts the urls are listed as '.../wordpress//...' instead of '.../wordpress/...'

How in SQL can I go through every row in the table and (perhaps use a regular expression) to replace every instance of 'ss//' with 'ss/'?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
UPDATE sometable SET somefield=REPLACE(somefield,'/wordpress//','/wordpress/');
```

**Edit**

@Kevin asked me to explain this query, so here we go:

- I assume the basic UPDATE is clear: In all rows of `sometable` assign a new value to `somefield`
- the `REPLACE()` function does exactly what it says: It replaces text. In our use case we ant it to take the old value of `somefield`, then replace all ocurrencies of '/wordpress//' with '/wordpress/'
- these two parts taken together mean, in all rows of `sometable` assign `somefield` the value, that results, if you replace all ocurrencies of '/wordpress//' with '/wordpress/' in the old value.

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: @Kevin I was quite sure, this is self-explaining! Anyway, I will add some explanation.

Comment: Great function and well explained!